# tslint: curly as-needed has no effect

Tags: typescript, tslint

https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/curly/

I checked the document and added this in my `tslint.json` file.

```
"curly": [
  true, "as-needed"
],
```

However, when I ran `tslint myapp.ts`, I still got error like below.

```
ERROR: express-app/app.ts[28, 5]: if statements must be braced
```

The *statement* it mentioned looks like this.

```
    if (server)
      server.close(() => console.log('closed'));
```

But I think with that *curly* configuration, *tslint* would allow me to write **if** statements like this.

### Environment

- tslint: 4.5.1
- typescript: 3.3.3333

#### Full tslint.json

```
{
  "extends": [
    "tslint:recommended"
  ],
  "jsRules": {},
  "rules": {
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single"
    ],
    "curly": [
      true, "as-needed"
    ],
    "radix": [
      false
    ],
    "arrow-parens": [
      true,
      "ban-single-arg-parens"
    ],
    "no-console": [
      true,
      "error"
    ]
  },
  "rulesDirectory": []
}
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce this but it worked correctly for me. What version of tslint and typescript are you using? Could you include more of your tslint.json file? Perhaps there is a problem somewhere else.

Comment: @Nicholas, updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `"as-needed"` option was added in [`tslint@5.4.0`](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/releases/tag/5.4.0).

To get it to work, update `tslint` to that version (by running `npm i -D tslint@^5.4.0`, or however else you like to update your dependencies).

Note this crosses a major version bump so there may be breaking changes.

Comment: Sorry, I changed it to *false* to avoid the error. But if use the value you gave, I still get the same error.

Comment: @David Sorry for my confusion. I've updated my answer to address what hopefully is the real problem.